# Call functions from function inside an object (object literal)

Tags: javascript, function, object-literal

I'm learning to use object literals in JS, and I'm trying to get a function inside an object to run by calling it through another function in the same object. Why isn't the function "run" running when calling it from the function "init"?

```
var RunApp = {

    init: function(){   
         this.run()
    },
    
    run: function() { 
             alert("It's running!");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

That code is only a **declaration**. You need to actually *call* the function:

```
RunApp.init();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/s6MJ5/

Answer (score 13):

There is nothing magical about the `init` property of an object, which you happen to have assigned a function to.  So if you don't call it, then it won't run.  No functions are ever executed for you when constructing an object literal like this.

As such, your code becomes this:

```
var RunApp = {
    init: function(){   
         this.run()
    },
    run: function() { 
         alert("It's running!");
    }
};

// Now we call init
RunApp.init();
```

Comment: This is not what he asked. He wants to call a function inside an object by calling it through another function in the same object.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code. It should work:

```
var RunApp = {

  init: function(){   
     RunApp.run()
  },

  run: function() { 
     alert("It's running!");
  }
};
```