# Custom JavaScript function not being called

Tags: javascript

I have written some custom function for image slider but it not get called

following is my code.

```
carousel: {
  init: function() {
      // main function to run
  }
  previous: function() {
     // function to run when they want to go back
  },
  next: function() {
    // function to run when they want to go forward
  }
}
```

and i am calling it like `onclick=javascript:previous()`
but I get the following error on console :

```
previous() not defined
```

Comment: can you share the error message from console?

Comment: in console it shows previous() not defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call functions from function inside an object (object literal)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219008/call-functions-from-function-inside-an-object-object-literal)

Comment: @GaneshGudghe Is your `carousel` property wrapped in another object?

Answer (score 1):

If `carousel` is the top level of that object.

You need to call the function previous by referring to it as the property of the object:

```
onclick=carousel.previous()
```

Comment: Actually they have `carousel: {` which makes it look like `carousel` is a property of some other object, so they need to access whatever the top most object is and access each property down to `previous`