# How to call Javascript function inside its own class?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am creating a Javascript class like so:

```
function Board(){
    this.initializePositionArray=function(){
        var tempPositionArray=[];
        tempPositionArray[0][0]="x";
        return tempPositionArray;
    };
    this.positionArray=initializePositionArray();
}
```

My aim is to initially fill `positionArray` with values using `initializePositionArray()`.  However, the call to `initializePositionArray()` gives the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: initializePositionArray is not defined
```

Comment: Missing `this` in context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call functions from function inside an object (object literal)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219008/call-functions-from-function-inside-an-object-object-literal)

Comment: @Rajesh it doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call it with `this`:

```
this.positionArray=this.initializePositionArray();
```

Because it is a property of your constructor and you were calling it  as a global function which is not defined.

Comment: Should you not look for dupes and close it?

Comment: Oh is it? not looked it though. and it doesn't seem to be dupe as per your suggestion.

Comment: @Rajesh, is it actually a duplicate?  I am defining my object in a different way than in the proposed duplicate question.

Comment: @sigil Its not about how you define the object. At the end you want to call a method inside same object. Yes accepted answer is not the desired answer but other answer addressed it correctly

Comment: @sigil this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918228/javascript-calling-object-methods-within-that-object