# Adding numbers within object method in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

Say I have the following object:

```
var my_object = {
    value1: "220",
    value2: "100",
    value3_1: "300",
    value3_2: "300",
    value3: function() {
        return +this.value3_1 + +value3_2;
    }
};
```

What do I need to do to make this work? In console, `my_object.value3` returns:

```
() {
        return +this.value3_1 + +this.value3_2;
    }
```

..instead of '600'.

Comment: Only `my_object.value3()`

Comment: Also fix the reference to `value3_2` — should be `this.value3_2`

Comment: Ahh! Of course. It's a function (Method) and thus I need the parenthesis. Thanks. Please feel free to post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call functions from function inside an object (object literal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219008/call-functions-from-function-inside-an-object-object-literal)

Comment: Use getter. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You possibly want to do this :

```
var my_object = {
 value1: "220",
 value2: "100",
 value3_1: 300,
 value3_2: 300,
 value3: function() {
    return +this.value3_1 + this.value3_2;
 }
};
```

and then call the function with this : `my_object.value3()`

Note: I added `this` in front of value3_2 and I changed the value of value3
_1 and value3_2 to numbers from string be removing the double quotes.

Comment: Perfect! I thought it was weird to have to write the plus in front of the strings, and since I'm using numbers for calculations then this makes more sense of course.

Answer (score 2):

### Use getter

```js
var my_object = {
 value1: 220,
 value2: 100,
 value3_1: 300,
 value3_2: 300,
 get value3() {
    return this.value3_1 + this.value3_2;
 }
};

console.log(my_object.value3);
```

This way you don't need to "know" which one is a function and which is not.

For example, say you need to read all values, you can do:

```
Object.keys(my_object).forEach(k => console.log(k, my_object[k]))
```

Whereas without getter, you'll need to:

```
Object.keys(my_object).forEach(k => console.log(k, 
    typeof my_object[k] === 'function' ? my_object[k]() : my_object[k]))
```

Comment: Perhaps knowing is a good thing? Especially for a newbie like me that is still struggling with syntax. It's there another raccoon for using get? What does is mean? Can't just use it if I don't understand it.

Comment: To me it looks like you are suing that you want to get a prop that doesn't exist (reversed word logic) and it makes me uncomfortable in that I'll remember it.

Comment: Updated my answer with examples. newbie or not, you deserve the answers.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that just introduced more questions like "what is key?", "is it a new object, even though my_object is an object literal and not a constructor?", "why write object first?", "Why is forEach appended to key?", "what is 'k'?". Sure, less code, so that's good. Perhaps I can revisit this and utilize it in a few months.

Comment: Objects (e.g my_object) are made of key:value pairs. Object.keys() is a function that will return an array of all the keys in a given object. .forEach is an array function that will callback the given function, for each element in the array.

Comment: Oh, that was easier to understand than expected. And "k" is just some variable and could be whatever instead of "k" specifically?

Comment: k (short for key) is just the argument of the arrow function (=>). you could use regular function too: `function(k) {console.log(k, my_object[k]); }`

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling a function, you need to use parenthesis (). So it should be *my_object.value3()*.

Also you have to replace *value3_2* with *this.value3_2*

Alternatively,
*value3_1* and *value3_2* are both numbers, so no need to give quotes. Simply you can write 300.

```
var my_object = {
  value1: 220,
  value2: 100,
  value3_1: 300,
  value3_2: 300,
  value3: function() {
    return this.value3_1 + this.value3_2;
 }
};
```